# Update current page number after page transition animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

Right now updating currentPagenumber when turning page over by using this statement

```
 [self displaycurrentIndex:currentIndex + 1];
```

in below method. It updates current pagenumber when page is not displayed yet. so that is why want to update it once page transition animation is done.

I want it should update cureent page number when transition animation is done. How can i write in code to update current pagenumber after page transition animation is done.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
   viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pages" ofType:@"pdf"];

NSURL *pdfurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfurl);

contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];

currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController page]];

if (currentIndex == totalPages - 1) {

    return nil;
}
contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex + 1];

[self displaycurrentIndex:currentIndex + 1];

return contentViewController;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

`UIPageViewControllerDelegate` has the following method:

`pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:`

Assign a delegate object to the UIPageViewController, and update the display of the page number within that method.

Comment: Yeah i tried that too. I m having issue with that one too. If you can help in solving that issue. please check my this question i posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732136/update-current-page-number-after-pageviewcontroller-animation-is-completed